# not picking up the first row of data into dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I am reading in a csv which looks like:

```
date        total_pnl_per_pos
10/01/2006             -0.027
11/01/2006         0.34400804
12/01/2006        0.894075999
13/01/2006       -0.221139488
```

However when I use the following code to read the .csv into a data-frame (df):

```
    for dirName,sundirList, fileList in os.walk(rootdir):
             print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
             for fname in fileList:
                 print('\t%s' % fname)
                 full_path = os.path.join(dirName, fname)
                 df = pd.read_csv(full_path, header=1, usecols=[0,15],parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True,index_col=[0], names=['date', 'total_pnl_per_pos'])
                 print(df)
```

I get the following returned:

```
            total_pnl_per_pos
date                         
11/01/2006           0.344008
12/01/2006           0.894076
13/01/2006          -0.221139
```

The first row of data is missing.  I've tried tinkering with the pd.read line but I can't retrieve the data for 10/01/2006.

Any assistance would be much apprenticed.
Thanks

Comment: Try remove `header=1` or use `header=0,`

Comment: silly me, header = 0 did the trick

Answer (score 0):

You need parameter `header=0` for read first row of file as column names.

Or remove parameter `names` if same values as column names, then is necessary remove `header=1` also.